# Android MIUI 13 upgrade: app permission messed up

Tags: applications, permissions, background-process, miui-13

After the upgrade from MIUI 12 to MIUI 13 on my Xiaomi Poco X3 NFC, the app permissions somehow got messed up. For example: I have some apps that usually run in the background and they now get inactive when locking the phone.

When I inspect the granted permissions of the app, they are shown as granted, but they are not. A workaround I found is uninstalling the app and installing it again, but this isn't a real solution for me.

Is there a way to let all apps ask again for their permission without reinstalling them?

P.S. the phone is stock, no root, no custom bootloader.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually caused by app permissions, it looks more like due to the [background process killer](https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi). Otherwise, you might want to clarify which permissions specifically since there are behavior changes on every Android update.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this seems to be the problem. This, plus setting the MIUI Battery Saving Mode to "Don't limit the app" for every affected app solved the problem.